# How am I supposed to write over an array given the number of times it has to be copied in Java

Tags: java, arrays, copy

I am supposed to "multiply" an array for given number of times, using the int copy variable. However, I am stuck on "writing over the array" as arrays can not be modified, and copying the array a given amount of times. Clearer instructions can be found below. Thanks! :)

```
int[] arrayMultiplier(int[] arr, int copies)
This method should return an array generated by writing the array arr
several (copies) times in a row.
For example if the array nums = [3, 5, 6]:
arrayMultiplier(nums, 3)
would return the array [3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6, 3, 5, 6]
```

I should clarify that I found two other posts on how to do this, but they used C++ and Javascript instead of Java

Answer (score 0):

Try creating the array you want to return from the multiplier

```
int[] multiplied = new int[arr.length * copies];
```

Then loop through  the new array and populate it.

```
for(int i = 0;i<=multiplied.length-1;i++){
   multiplied[i] = arr[i%copies];
}
```

Comment: "arr[i%copies]" : how will this work? I suppose for three copies, arr[0%3]=arr[0],arr[1%3]=arr[1],arr[2%3]=arr[2],arr[3%3]=arr[0]. Am I right. And will this store the values in contiguous locations in the memory.

Comment: @coder kemp  There should be 2 arrays.  a larger one that is the size of the first times the number of copies,  which is why modulus will work nicely to assign the values of the smaller array to locations larger than it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ArrayList then convert it into an array when you return it. Probably not the most efficient answer, but it works.

```
public int[] arrayMultiplier(int[] arr, int copies) {
    ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i = 0; i < copies; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            temp.add(arr[j]);
        }
    }
    return temp.stream().mapToInt(i->i).toArray();
}
```